# Tools or communities for word association?

Tags: word-choice, tools, resources

Are there any tools or online communities that deal with word association? I'm looking for a resource where I could poll for common associations for a particular word.  If you do know of such a tool or community, please describe its positives and negatives.

Comment: I've edited your question a bit. "What kind of tools do you use?" is a very chatty, open-ended question, and wouldn't work well here. Similarly, the details of why you can't ask about word association on Stack Exchange isn't necessary.

Comment: The kind folks in the English Language & Usage chatroom might also have some ideas on this.

Answer (score 1):

Two resources that sound appropriate are:

- http://wordassociations.net/
- http://www.wordassociation.org/search/

Though I can't rule it out, I kind of doubt you'll find existed dedicated communities - I expect very few people are interested in regularly checking into a site for the sole purpose of answering word association requests. On writing forums, you might find some people happy to do you a favor by answering, but your requests will probably not be the scintillating discussions forums prefer...

What you *could* do is just collect the words you're interested in, and ask a handful of friends to give you some associations for each. Simple, friendly, and 100% human.

Comment: Thanks. I found similar sites myself before posting on here but I was hoping to get associations from humans, not a database… I guess my best bet is to find a writers' forum.